# Filter Type.GetProperties() where PropertyType.Name is in a List

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to show only the properties that have names that are in the requiredfield list.

I'm trying to do something like this but p.PropertyType.Name == x is not correct:

```
Pricing pricing = new Pricing();
Type type = typeof(Pricing);
PropertyInfo[] PricingProperties = type.GetProperties();

PricingRequiredFieldDAL requiredField = new PricingRequiredFieldDAL();

var x = requiredField.GetRequiredFields();

var list = PricingProperties.Where(p => p.PropertyType.Name == x);

public class PricingRequiredFieldDAL
{
    PricingContext db = new PricingContext();

    public List<PricingRequiredField> GetRequiredFields()
    {
        return db.PricingRequiredFields.Where(p => p.Required == true).ToList();
    }
}
```

How would I go about getting the information I want using reflection in the above fashion?

Comment: What is the type of x? requiredField is a PricingRequiredFieldDAL type but the GetRequiredFields() method makes it seem like x would be something that inherits from IEnumerable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just something like:

```
var fieldNames = new HashSet<string>(x.Select(p => p.Name));
var properties = PricingProperties.Where(p => fieldNames.Contains(p.Name));
```

That's assuming that `PricingRequiredField` has a property called `Name`. You haven't actually told us that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var list = PricingProperties.Where(p => x.Contains(p.PropertyType.Name));
```

I supposed x is a list.